# How to make two segue functions?

Tags: ios, swift, segue

How to make two segue override functions?

```
@IBAction func doneBut(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("Done")
    if pointInput.text!.characters.count < 500 {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toResult", sender: self)
    }
    else {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toWinner", sender: self)
    }

}
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toResult" {
        if segue.destination is ResultViewController {

        }
    }
}
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toWinner" {
        if segue.destination is ResultViewController {

        }
    }
}
```

When i did another override function - an error is

> 'prepare(for:sender:)' has already been overridden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override `prepare(for` only once and distinguish the segues by `switch`ing on the `identifier`:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    switch segue.identifier {
      case "toResult":
        let destination = segue.destination as! ResultViewController 
        // prepare something

      case "toWinner":
        let destination = segue.destination as! ResultViewController 
        // prepare something

      default: break
    }
}
```

To switch the input on an `Int` value use this version with type checking:

```
@IBAction func doneBut(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("Done")
    guard let inputText = pointInput.text, let inputInt = Int(inputText) else { 
          // inform the user about the error if needed
          return 
    }
    if inputInt < 500 {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toResult", sender: self)
    }  else {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toWinner", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: If user in input 500 and more - segue to the VC A, else if input less than 500 - segue to the VC B (segue for a button)! How can i do it? Please help

Comment: Just  use your `IBAction` in the question and `prepare(for segue` in my answer. If you don't need to pass any parameters to the destination view controller you can omit `prepare(for segue` completely.

Comment: is it correct  <<@IBAction func doneBut(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("Done")
        if Int(pointInput.text!)! < 500 {
            print("Result")
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toResult", sender: self)
        }
        if Int(pointInput.text!)! >= 500 {
            print("Winner")
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toWinner", sender: self)
        }
    }
>>

Comment: I understand and added a more reliable solution to the answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can only override it once. Use `if` statements to match different identifiers. Try this.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toResult" {
        if segue.destination is ResultViewController {

        }
    } else if segue.identifier == "toWinner" {
        if segue.destination is ResultViewController {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you should not write the same function two times. That is exactly what this error saying.

> 'prepare(for:sender:)' has already been overridden

The function is already overriden.

Try writing like this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toResult" {
        if segue.destination is ResultViewController {

        }
    else  if segue.identifier == "toWinner" {
        if segue.destination is ResultViewController {

        }
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to understand your problem from error message.

> 'prepare(for:sender:)' has already been overridden

you can not have same method(With same defination) more then once in same class it is against OOP.

---

Assume that in the morning your father says that "at 8:00 AM you have to go to school any how". 
And after some times your mother come and tell you that "at 8:00 AM you have to go to your aunts home to help her".

Now you become confuse and little bit anger too because you don't know what you will going to do at 8:00 AM ?
This is what happens with your compiler too and show error that please let me know one thing what to do when you call this function "prepare(for:sender:)"

---

You already know the solutions of your problem so not posting here.
Here I am just want you to know that it is easy to solve our problem if we understand it well. 
as par my opinion [vadian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45005844/914538) has nice solution for you,